# emu8086 - compiling takes a really long time and program doesn't work

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I Have written this code in emu8086.
When I press emulate it takes a really long time to compile the code and when it is compiled it works weirdly incorrectly. (instead of jumping to main it jumps to the function max etc.)

And before you say there might be a problem with "magshimim.inc", there isn't, it works in other files.

```
include magshimim.inc

org  100h

jmp main

;--------------------------------------------;
; Functions
;--------------------------------------------;

; This function gets 2 numbers and an address.
; It stores the biggest number in the address.
; Input:
;   push result_address
;   push num1
;   push num2
PROC max

    ; store offset of parameters relative to bp
    result_p    equ     6
    num1        equ     4
    num2        equ     2

    push    bp      ; store the previous stack frame
    mov     bp, sp  ; create new stack frame
    push    ax      ; store ax

    mov ax, [bp+num1]
    cmp ax, [bp+num2]
    jng num1_bigger_num2

    num1_bigger_num2:
        mov ax, [bp+num1]
        mov [[bp+result_p]], ax
        jmp skip1

    num1_not_bigger_num2:
        mov ax, [bp+num2]
        mov [[bp+result_p]], ax

    skip1:

    pop     ax      ; re-store ax
    mov     sp, bp  ; close stack frame
    pop     bp      ; re-store the previous stack frame

ret
ENDP


;--------------------------------------------;
; Global variables
;--------------------------------------------;

    result      dw  0
    num0        dw  2
    num1        dw  10

;--------------------------------------------;
; Main
;--------------------------------------------;

main:  

    push offset result
    push num0
    push num1
    call max
    add sp, 6

    mov ax, result
    call print_num

    mov ah, 0
    int 16h

ret
```

Comment: I just ran your code in my EMU and it jumped to main as soon as it started.

Comment: I think it's a problem in my pc.

Comment: Do this : cut the procedure "max" and paste it below the final "ret".

Comment: Another solution : divide your code in segments, you know, stack, data, code.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez Can you show me how to do it, I actually don't know

Comment: Are you sure moving the procedure to the bottom didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ; store offset of parameters relative to bp
> result_p    equ     6
> num1        equ     4
> num2        equ     2
> ```

Your program doesn't work because you're using the wrong offsets to retrieve the procedures arguments!
When the instruction `mov ax, [bp+num1]` is executed the stack contains the following (from lower addresses to higher addresses):

```
Old AX
      Old BP
      ^     Return Address
      |                   Value 10
      |                           Value 2
Current BP points to here!               Offset result
      |----> +2
      |------------------> +4   
      |--------------------------> +6
      |---------------------------------> +8
```

This leads to these corrected equates:

```
result_p    equ     8
num1        equ     6
num2        equ     4
```

---

> ```
>  mov ax, [bp+num1]
>  cmp ax, [bp+num2]
>  jng num1_bigger_num2
> num1_bigger_num2:
> ```

Here's a second problem. When the outcome of the comparison is *greater than* you fall through in the code beneath, but when the outcome is *not greater than* you jump to the self-same code! That clearly can't work. The solution is to jump to the _num1_not_bigger_num2_ label.

```
    mov ax, [bp+num1]
    cmp ax, [bp+num2]
    jng num1_not_bigger_num2    <-- corrected
num1_bigger_num2:
    mov ax, [bp+num1]
    mov [bp+result_p], ax       <-- corrected
    jmp skip1
num1_not_bigger_num2:
```

---

> ```
> mov [[bp+result_p]], ax
> ```

I don't know why EMU8086 would accept these redundant square brackets. Best just use **a single pair of []** when addressing memory.

---

To make your life easier you should be consistent when naming your variables.
In the *main* part you have in order:

```
num1, num0, offset result
```

but in the *proc* you have in order:

```
num2, num1, result_p
```

This is very confusing and error prone!

---

> ```
> include magshimim.inc
> org  100h
> jmp main
> ```

You've said that there's no problem with this include file, but I would advice you to put the include below the `jmp main` instruction. The `org 100h` tells that you're compiling for a .COM file and the `jmp main` must be the first instruction on the execution path. You don't want any instructions from the include file to come before this important `jmp main`.

```
org  100h
jmp main
include magshimim.inc
```